# use markjs to count number of regex matches of certain class

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using [mark.js](http://mark.io/) as a regex aid to highlight matches in a string.

for example:

```
//negative assertions
instance.markRegExp(/not significant/g, {className: "negative"});
instance.markRegExp(/not associated/g, {className: "negative"});
instance.markRegExp(/no association/g, {className: "negative"});
//positive assertions
instance.markRegExp(/is associated/g, {className: "positive"});
instance.markRegExp(/are associated/g, {className: "positive"});
instance.markRegExp(/was associated/g, {className: "positive"});
```

I would like to be able to count the number of times a **class of matches** has occurred.

The [documentation](https://markjs.io/#filter) shows a callback feature but I'm unsure if I can use it for this purpose

```
var options = {
"filter": function(node, term, totalCounter, counter){
    if(term === "the" && counter >= 10){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: What do you want to do after you've received the current counter?

Comment: just store in a var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda simple. You can either use the `each` or the `done` callback, both provde a counter. With the `done` callback you don't need to count it yourself, you receive the number of all marks, thus it's easier for you. Furthermore the `done` callback is better for performance, since it isn't necessary to call the function on each mark.

Here's the code:

```js
var instance = new Mark(".context"),
  negativeCounter = 0,
  positiveCounter = 0;

//negative assertions
instance.markRegExp(/not significant/g, {
  className: "negative",
  done: function(counter) {
    negativeCounter += counter;
  }
});
instance.markRegExp(/not associated/g, {
  className: "negative",
  done: function(counter) {
    negativeCounter += counter;
  }
});
instance.markRegExp(/no association/g, {
  className: "negative",
  done: function(counter) {
    negativeCounter += counter;
  }
});
//positive assertions
instance.markRegExp(/is associated/g, {
  className: "positive",
  done: function(counter) {
    positiveCounter += counter;
  }
});
instance.markRegExp(/are associated/g, {
  className: "positive",
  done: function(counter) {
    positiveCounter += counter;
  }
});
instance.markRegExp(/was associated/g, {
  className: "positive",
  done: function(counter) {
    positiveCounter += counter;
  }
});

document.write("Positive counter: " + positiveCounter + ", Negative counter: " + negativeCounter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.8.3/mark.min.js"></script>
<div class="context">
  not significant not significant not associated no association is associated are associated was associated
</div>
```

Here are some notes:

1. mark.js works asynchronously. Theoretically you should nest the `.mark()` calls in the `done` callback. However, since you've not enabled the iframes option it works. But it's safer if you do this
2. To reduce the amount of `.mark()` calls and to make your code easier, you should create one RegExp for negative and one for positive matches, e.g. using RegExp groups.

Comment: thank you, that works. I was going to use this type of thing: positive_count =  positive_count + source.match(/are associated/g).length until I saw your answer